# Jaxb2Marshaller's classesToBeBound property

Tags: spring, jaxb, jaxb2

I am trying to configure `Jaxb2Marshaller` like below:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.test.response1.ResponseType1</value>
            <value>com.test.response2.ResponseType2</value>
            <value>com.test.request.Request</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And it works.

The confusion is dose the order of the classes mentioned in `classesToBound` matter ?

If I change it to:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
                        <value>com.test.request.Request</value>
            <value>com.test.response1.ResponseType1</value>
            <value>com.test.response2.ResponseType2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

With everything exactly the same I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'com.test.response2.ResponseType2' to required type 'com.test.request.Request'
```

The version of `spring` being used is: `3.1.2.RELEASE`

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless something has changed between Spring 3.1.0 and 3.1.2, the order does not matter if you are dealing with JAXB-generated classes.  If you are creating/annotating the objects by hand, that may be another story -- maybe if you post them, we can help.  On another note, I would highly suggest using another mechanism for pointing the `Jaxb2Marshaller` to the classes that you want to marshal, using either the `contextPaths` or `packagesToScan` properties.  Keep in mind that `contextPath`/`contextPaths` needs the `ObjectFactory` classes that are generated by the JAXB compiler.